# Affect on the system after revoking and requesting the certificate from other system

Tags: ios6

What will be the affect on the system with the certificate which is being revoked and  requested from the other system.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with revoking certificate from other system.You can also generate certificate using keychain of other system and use the same.But if you want to use the same certificate for an application already present in App store and you want to submit an update with new certificate you have to use same App id as previous app.